# UDP always listening over LAN in background

Tags: c#, udp, lan

I'm trying to use UDP over LAN, as you can see here I send one package with one pc to the other, but is it possible to send packets while you are still listining because when I start receiving the process stops responding.
I know this has something to do with Threads but I need a little help.
I appreciate all help, thanks in advance.

```
UdpClient client = new UdpClient();

public void SendPacket()
{
    byte[] packet = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss:ff"));
    client.Send(packet, packet.Length, tbIP.Text, 444);
    dgvSend.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss:ff"));
}

public void ReceivePacket()
{
    client = new UdpClient(444);
    IPEndPoint server = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
    byte[] packet = client.Receive(ref server);
    dgvReceiv.Rows.Add(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(packet), DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss:ff"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you `Receive` something you need to start another `Receive` in order to receive something from someone else.

Typically you'd use asynchronous IO if you want to receive multiple connections.  For example:

```
var client = new UdpClient(endPoint);
AsyncCallback callback = null;
callback = ar =>
            {
            IPEndPoint newIncomingEndPoint = endPoint;
            byte[] data = client.EndReceive(ar, ref newIncomingEndPoint);
            client.BeginReceive(callback, null);
                        // TODO: do something with data
            };
client.BeginReceive(callback, null);
```

Or, if you're more comfortable with something that doesn't use anonymous methods (from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.beginreceive.aspx):

```
public static bool messageReceived = false;

public static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
  UdpClient u = (UdpClient)((UdpState)(ar.AsyncState)).u;
  IPEndPoint e = (IPEndPoint)((UdpState)(ar.AsyncState)).e;

  Byte[] receiveBytes = u.EndReceive(ar, ref e);
  string receiveString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);

  Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", receiveString);
  messageReceived = true;
}

public static void ReceiveMessages()
{
  // Receive a message and write it to the console.
  IPEndPoint e = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, listenPort);
  UdpClient u = new UdpClient(e);

  UdpState s = new UdpState();
  s.e = e;
  s.u = u;

  Console.WriteLine("listening for messages");
  u.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), s);

  // Do some work while we wait for a message. For this example, 
  // we'll just sleep 
  while (!messageReceived)
  {
    Thread.Sleep(100);
  }
}
```

If you don't use async IO you can't receive another connection while you're processing the existing `Receive`--so you have a huge gap in time where something that wants to connect might get refused.

Comment: Hi, I've seen this code before but I still don't quite get it since you still have to wait to receive something in order to send. My point is to send while listening at the same time. FYI the code is incomplete since there is no UdpState class, thanks

Comment: Well, you don't really listen, you just receive.  With `Receive` you have to send before you receive, with `BeginReceive` you can start another receive while you're sending a response to whomever just sent something to you.